# errors while converting project from borland builder c++ 6 to embarcadero xe3

Tags: c++, borland-c++, c++builder-xe3

From few days i'm trying to convert project from borland c++ 6 to embarcadero xe3 and i still don't know what to do now.

I have many errors like "E2293 ) expected" but i know its not the reason why my program wont work.

In borland 6 it all works fine but here i have a lot of errors. How can i solve the problem with system.types.hpp , posix.systypes.hpp and posix.dlfcn.hpp ?

```
      [bcc32 Error] System.Types.hpp(511): E2293 ) expected
        Kons.cpp(3): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\vcl.h
    vcl.h(10): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\windows\vcl\basepch0.h
    basepch0.h(63): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\System.Types.hpp
          System.Types.hpp(38): namespace System
          System.Types.hpp(40): namespace Types

    [bcc32 Error] Posix.SysTypes.hpp(20): E2209 Unable to open include file 'pthread.h'
          KonsHydExpres.cpp(3): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\vcl.h
          vcl.h(10): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\windows\vcl\basepch0.h
          basepch0.h(68): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\System.SysUtils.hpp
          System.SysUtils.hpp(19): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\Posix.Dirent.hpp
          Posix.Dirent.hpp(18): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\Posix.SysTypes.hpp

  [bcc32 Error] Posix.SysTypes.hpp(63): E2257 , expected
      KonsHydExpres.cpp(3): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\vcl.h
      vcl.h(10): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\windows\vcl\basepch0.h
      basepch0.h(68): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\System.SysUtils.hpp
      System.SysUtils.hpp(19): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\Posix.Dirent.hpp
      Posix.Dirent.hpp(18): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\Posix.SysTypes.hpp
      Posix.SysTypes.hpp(23): namespace Posix
      Posix.SysTypes.hpp(25): namespace Systypes

  [bcc32 Error] Posix.Dlfcn.hpp(20): E2209 Unable to open include file 'dlfcn.h'
      KonsHydExpres.cpp(3): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\vcl.h
      vcl.h(10): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\windows\vcl\basepch0.h
      basepch0.h(68): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\System.SysUtils.hpp
      System.SysUtils.hpp(20): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\Posix.Dlfcn.hpp

  [bcc32 Error] Posix.Dlfcn.hpp(27): E2257 , expected
      KonsHydExpres.cpp(3): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\vcl.h
      vcl.h(10): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\windows\vcl\basepch0.h
      basepch0.h(68): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\System.SysUtils.hpp
      System.SysUtils.hpp(20): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\vcl\Posix.Dlfcn.hpp
      Posix.Dlfcn.hpp(23): namespace Posix
      Posix.Dlfcn.hpp(25): namespace Dlfcn
```

sample of the source code:

```
 #include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "OProgramie.h"
#include "About.h"
//#include<string>
#include "CommandLine.h"
#include "MenuLoader.h"

//---------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TAboutBox *AboutBox;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------- 



__fastcall TAboutBox::TAboutBox(TComponent* AOwner)
    : TForm(AOwner)
{

        vector<AnsiString> v = Split(AppDate," ");
        AnsiString d = v[0]+"/"+v[1]+"/"+v[2];

        Memo1->Lines->Strings[3] = d;
        Memo1->Lines->Strings[8] = menu.GetCaption("About","1");
        try{
                ProgramIcon->Picture->LoadFromFile(ExtractFileDir(Application->ExeName)+"\\icon\\bhmw.jpg");
        }catch(...){}
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TAboutBox::OKButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  Close();        
}
```

Comment: nobody know how to help?

Comment: Nobody can help without seeing your source code. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i don't know in which part of code is problem, but i cant post here too much of code

Comment: i added sample of the source code, maybe this could help to solve problem

Comment: that's far from MINIMAL . It doesn't work for me because `OProgramie.h` is not there. Try again.

Comment: every file is there, for sure OProgramie.h
i can't add enough code to minimal.  this is a big project and i'm not allowed to share with it.
Maybe i will just stay with borland 6

Comment: Hi! I did a similar thing some years ago to move to XE2. This error can occur, when you mess with `_WIN32_WINNT`. I set it to `0x0400` at some point and when vcl.h is loaded afterwards you get an `[BCC32 error] Winapi.Windows.hpp(923): E2257 , expected`.